# Unable to connect to remote server locally

Tags: json, webrequest, streamwriter

```
string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CorreURL"].ToString(); https://ourwebsite.com/Transmit

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(claim, Formatting.Indented);

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "passwordgoesherebuthiddenfromstackoverflow");
                
Type type = request.GetType();
Object currentMethod = type.GetProperty("CurrentMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(request);

Type methodType = currentMethod.GetType();
methodType.GetField("ContentBodyNotAllowed", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(currentMethod, false);

//i get the error here:
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
   streamWriter.Write(json);
}
```

What I am trying to do is send a json file (that file is ok as I tested it on lint) to our server to process the file.  We use postman and i got the creds from there but to no luck.  I hope this is enough info.  Please let me know if I need to provide more.  The above code is all the code just pw hidden.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to provide a bit more information on the response, it could be anything from firewall blocking your application to you using the endpoint incorrectly. I.e you are using HTTP GET and the endpoint could be POST

Comment: Unable to connect to remote server is the only message i get.  I looked at the request object and it looks ok.  Where else can I look?  Thanks for your help

Comment: You hit it on the head.  It seems I am blocked as I tried it on the server and it worked.  Thanks!